# Cant keep search bar centered in header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a searchbar toward the bottom of my header, centered horizontally. It looks perfect on my main screen, but when I make the window smaller or view the site on a smaller screen it isn't responsive. I am not sure what I didn't do, or what I did that is causing it to not be responsive. Below is the code pertaining to it, any help would be great!

HTML for SearchBar:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label hidden="true" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input placeholder="I want to go see lighthouses" class="text" type="text" value="I want to go see lighthouses" name="I want to go see lighthouses" id="s" onfocus="(this.value == 'I want to go see lighthouses') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'I want to go see lighthouses')" />
    <input hidden="true" type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Search!" />
  </div>
</form>
```

HTML for header:

```
<div class="outcont">
<div id="top" class="header">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="col1"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - Return to the homepage"><img class="logoi" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/main-logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Logo" /></a></div>
<div class="col2"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'global-nav', 'container' => '')); ?></div>
</div>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#searchform div {
  margin-left: 31%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  margin-right: 31%;
  shadow: 4px 7px 4px #000000;
}

#searchform .text {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 220%;
  color: #B7B7B7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: white url('images/search-img.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 96% center;
}

#searchform .text:focus {
  background-image: none;
}

#searchform .text img {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Did you want the search bar to be dead center of the container?

Comment: dead center horizontally, and just a little bit below the center vertically. My main concern is getting it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use flexbox within your css.

I would suggest removing all your margin percentages since they will always look different on different screen sizes.

Within your #searchform div css I would change it to:

```
#searchform div {
  shadow: 4px 7px 4px #000000;
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This will make it center and you can change the top margin to make it to your desired height. This will also keep it center responsively.

Here's a fiddle to show the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dkoggq3/

I added a container and made it light gray so that you can see the container with the centered content.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing now, which isn't a huge issue, is that top margin. I got it to where I wanted on my main screen, but when I view it on a smaller screen size it is lower down the header.

Comment: You can use media queries to specify a change within a screen size. Try adding `@media (max-width: 480px) { #searchform div { margin-top: 200px} ` Right here you are basically saying at this screen size, make the margin-top 200px for my #searchform div